# How to show toolbar ( and hide current ) when click on the next item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to show toolbar (and hide current) when i click on next similar element? in my code, when i click on next similar element, toolbar doesn't disappear, he disappears only if i firsly click on body and then on element, how to remove toolbar without clicking to body to show next toolbar? thx! 
http://jsfiddle.net/wwL8fgr1/1/

```
$(".element").on('mouseup', function(e){

        $('[el-button]').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        var toolbar  = $('<div class="dm-popover"></div>');

        if ( !$('.dm-popover').hasClass('in') ) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                toolbar.addClass('in');
            },100);
            $('body').prepend(toolbar);
        }

        toolbar.addClass('dm-link-frontend-control-top');

        toolbar.css({
            left: $(this).offset().left,
            top:  $(this).offset().top - toolbar.height() - 10  
        });

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').on('mouseup', function(e){
                if($(e.target).closest(toolbar).length == 0){
                    $('body').unbind('click', arguments.callee);
                        toolbar.removeClass('in');
                        toolbar.remove();
                }
            });
        }, 100);

        e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$(".element").on('mouseup', function(e){

            $('[el-button]').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            if ( !$('.dm-popover').hasClass('in') ) 
            {
                var toolbar  = $('<div class="dm-popover"></div>');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    toolbar.addClass('in');
                },100);
                $('body').prepend(toolbar);
            }
            else
            {
                var toolbar  = $('.dm-popover');
            }    

            toolbar.addClass('dm-link-frontend-control-top');

            toolbar.css({
                left: $(this).offset().left,
                top:  $(this).offset().top - toolbar.height() - 10  
            });

            setTimeout(function(){
                $('body').on('mouseup', function(e){
                    if($(e.target).closest(toolbar).length == 0){
                        $('body').unbind('click', arguments.callee);
                            toolbar.removeClass('in');
                            toolbar.remove();
                    }
                });
            }, 100);

            e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

See the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wwL8fgr1/3/

Comment: Is that all you want? then i can explain what was wrong in your logic earlier

Comment: YES! amazing, but i have one more thing, i can click on toolbar and add class to inner element, but when i click on next element, class of inner element don't disappear: http://take.ms/PuDcL and can you explain what i miss in my code? thx)

Comment: The issue that was there in you code was you were creating the toolbar element on every click on element, but you was appending it for the first time so all the css that you were applying was for the toolbar that you have created not to the toolbar that was already appended

Answer (score 0):

The code responsible for removing the toolbar is here:

```
$('body').on('mouseup', function(e){
    if($(e.target).closest(toolbar).length == 0){
        $('body').unbind('click', arguments.callee);
        toolbar.removeClass('in');
        toolbar.remove();
    }
});
```

Note this registers a `mouseup` handler on `body`. That's why you need to click on `body` to remove the toolbar. You can attach this handler to the second element, if that's what you expect.

**EDIT**

My guess is that you wanted to achieve something like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjhhdn5q/). Note that is is suitable for 2 elements only, if you need more *similar elements*, you'd probably need to make a function to generate id's for you instead of storing them in `data-` attributes.

My opinion:

Your code seems overly complex - you're using timeouts, swapping css, `mouseup` instead of `click`, creating `div` elements on each click, preventing handler's propagation... Try to make it simpler by removing unnecessary stuff.

Comment: "You can attach this handler to the second element"  - don't understand what do you mean )

Comment: I mean something like this: `$(".element").on('mouseup', function(e){ /* remove toolbar here */ });`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you need, then? It's not very clear to me.